# Bulma and Ionicons

Tags: svelte, bulma, ionicons

I am using Svelte, Bulma, and (trying to use) Ionicons. The icons do not render. I think it's due to my incorrect placement of the ionicons loading script.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<i class="ion-ionic add-circle-outline"></i>
```

The Ionicons script is below:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure where the above script goes. I tried at the bottom of my App.svelte page but no luck. I also tried enclosing it in a  tag.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use next with bulma

```
<span class="ion-ionic">
<ion-icon name="add-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where does your code come from, the official document says there is a specific usage.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
<ion-icon name="add-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
```

https://ionicons.com/usage

Comment: With svelte-component you must add `<svelte:head>` tags around `<script src>` like this `<svelte:head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.1.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>
</svelte:head>
<ion-icon name="add-circle-outline"></ion-icon>`

Comment: @zmag Yes the code for bulma is a bit different than std usage in Ionic, thus the <i> tag.

Comment: @grohjy - I put the script tag inside <svelte:head> but no luck. The Ionicons docs say the src tag needs to be at the bottom of the body tag. Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: font awesome works fine. Also, if I don't use bulma life is good too.  Something with Bulma and ionicons.

Answer (score 0):

The icon element is a container.

```
<span class="icon is-small has-text-link has-background-grey-lighter">
  <!-- Font Awesome 6 -->
  <i class="fa-sharp fa-regular fa-chevron-right"></i>

  <!-- Font Awesome 5 -->
  <i class="far fa-chevron-right"></i>

  <!-- Material Design Icons -->
  <span class="mdi mdi-chevron-right"></span>

  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
</span>
```

Please specify the icon element outside.